# How to display native-resolution console on the monitor after booting without one?

Tags: hdmi, terminal

I've started my Raspberry Pi Model B without having any monitor plugged. Then I plugged the HDMI monitor, but got no signal. So far I've been able to turn it on by using the command:

```
tvservice --preferred
```

But it only turns the monitor on and sets the preferred display mode, while the screen is still blank. I've then been able to reset to low-resolution console by starting Xorg with the command

```
startx /usr/bin/lxterminal
```

(which runs in low resolution itself) and then just typed `exit` into the terminal.

The problem is that the resulting console is still low-resolution, and the way I got it is far from being elegant.

How can I get the native-resolution console after booting up without monitor, without rebooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching I've found the solution:

1. `tvservice --preferred` (monitor turns on)
2. Alt+F2, Alt+F1 to switch to VT2 and back to VT1 (console text appears)
3. `fbset -g 1920 1080 1920 1080 32` (resolution becomes 1920x1080)

Thanks to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69728/20014).